# Is it possible to drag&drop line precisely 6 meters to right or left?

Tags: qgis

I use Quantum GIS 2.2.0 Valmiera

I have a polyline layer. I can drag&drop polyline nodes by using "Node Tool". Is it possible to drag&drop line precisely 6 meters to right or left?

Comment: Try QGIS plugin Affine Transformations. [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/how-to-move-vectors-to-specified-coordinates-in-qgis][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/how-to-move-vectors-to-specified-coordinates-in-qgis

Comment: you mean to offset it to its left or right?