# Shape of polygons does not adjust to new position after translating in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, translation

I want to translate the polygon in this shapefile (PMNM_py.shp, http://sanctuaries.noaa.gov/library/imast/pmnm_py.zip) from its initial position (NW of Hawaii) to central Europa to give somebody living in Europa an idea of the massive scale of this marine sanctuary using QGIS.

I can move it via editing mode/view->select features/edit->move feature(s) to its new position but I don't see the shape getting distorted (This should happen because I move the poly to another location in the same projection).

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Moving a feature does not translate it. You could use the **Vector Affine Transformation** plugin as described in this post: [QGIS moving the layer/all features using Vector Affine Transformation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136817/qgis-moving-the-layer-all-features-using-vector-affine-transformation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

translating/moving features was the wrong concept for comparing the size of geographic areas with each other on one static map.
I solved it with using costum CRS (azimuthal orthographic) for different layers. one for the basemap and the shape of the sanctuary (center of projecion = centroid of sanctuary) and one for the map of europa (center of projecion = city of zurich). important for this case was to dissable 'on the fly' CRS transformation in the project properties.

[image]