# How to offset polyline geometries (not symbology) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line

I have a polyline layer which has a road network digitized, up the center, in both directions however the polyline are sat "one on top of the other".

I can display the lines separately by "offsetting" through the symbology however what i need is to change the actual positions of the lines by an offset so that the lines are then separate ( not sitting on top of each other)for exporting as a KML.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: [This Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/how-to-move-vectors-to-specified-coordinates-in-qgis) may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out using postgis, if you have access to that.  I'm pretty new to postgis so perhaps there's a better way than this but it worked for me. I loaded the original shapefile as a table, then i did the following query.  You'll have to add any columns you want from the original table to the query, represented below as column1, column2.

CREATE TABLE schema_name.newtable_name
AS SELECT 
original_table_name.column1, 
original_table_name.column2, 
st_offsetcurve(original_table_name.geom, 'offset number') AS offset_geom,
FROM original_table_name;

You can connect to the postgres database directly from QGIS and from there you should be able to export as a kml. Here's more about st_offsetcurve  http://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html

good luck!