# Moving circle using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, circle

Using QGIS 2.2, I want to move a circle from one specific point to another specific point: How can i grab the exact center of the circle and move it to another location without creating points in the center of the circles?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to decide which question is the more important for you to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Gis SE.
If you want to move objects in QGIS you can use the "Move Feature(s) tool" in the editing toolbox.

[image]

Start to edit your layer containing the circles, then click on the circle you want to move and move it to the other position.

After the editing you have to save your changes.

If you want to move the circle to specific coordinates you can have a look at this question:
  [Moving vectors to specified coordinates in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/how-to-move-vectors-to-specified-coordinates-in-qgis)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already know the "move feature-tool". unfourtunately your answer did not solve my problem: i want to pick the circle in the center and move it exactly over another circle. to do this it is recommended that i can pick the circle at the center and that the objectfang logs the center of the second circle.