# Moving layer across map canvas

Tags: qgis-3, layers, translation

I would like to move my created layer across the map canvas.

[image: example1]

I found some solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13433/moving-vectors-to-specified-coordinates-in-qgis). And next tried to achieve something similar in QGIS 3.10.

[image: example2]

Unfortunately, this step couldn't be achieved, as I am getting an error:

> This algorithm cannot be run :-(  The specified GRASS 7 folder
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin\bin" does not contain a valid set of GRASS
>   7 modules. Please, go to the Processing settings dialog, and check
>   that the GRASS 7 folder is correctly configured

Is there any way to move the layer at the specified distance across the map canvas?

**UPDATE:**

I toggled to edit mode of the layer and selected it in the vertex tool. Now I have all nodes active:

[image]

Is there a way to move them all at once?

Comment: Try the "translate" algorithm instead (the one in the Geometry group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is one option:**

If you have a feature you want to manually move then you would need to enable the advanced digitizing toolbar and use the move feature tool. You can then view the distance in the X and Y plane as well as the bearing. To do this follow the steps taken in the GIF below:

[image]

Comment: The major option of advanced digitizing tools is unavailable (I mean the ruler at the very left), however I am able to solve my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Apologies - to get this you also need to enable the advanced digitizing panel

Comment: OK, but how to do it?

Comment: Right click on any of the buttons (the pencil for example) and enable advanced digitizing under panels.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using QGIS Desktop 3.10.1 with GRASS 7.8.1 (as opposed to plain QGIS Dekstop 3.10.1), this should enable the GRASS modules. Search for it from the start menu.

Comment: I have the GRASS 7.8.1, but I can't find the menu

Comment: When you run QGIS, are you using the version that is just called QGIS Desktop 3.10.1, or the one called QGIS Desktop 3.10.1 with GRASS 7.8.1? Look in the folder where the app is stored, there should be different versions.