# Stacking two vectors using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

Although the coordinate systems in QGIS for 2 different vector layers are the same, there are differences between the boundaries.

How can I superimpose this data?

[image]

---

With the plugin or another way, I can overlap this, not with the coordinate system, because they are both in the same coordinate. I think this is because the drawings are wrong but I couldn't find the solution

Comment: This looks to be similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/348017 - you might check that question for suggestions.

Comment: Also, someone with a higher reputation might want to look at marking this as a duplicate question.

Comment: You can flag as duplicate.

Comment: Looks like a different issue to me. Could it be that your two lines just come from different data sources with different accuracy? You could try 'snap geometries to a layer' in processing toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the **Snap geometries to layer** processing tool:

> This algorithm snaps the geometries in a layer. Snapping can be done
>   either to the geometries from another layer, or to geometries within
>   the same layer.

[image]